# Does every congruence class modulo m has an inverse pairing?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

For example for mod 11 I get that all the congruence classes of it has an inverse pairing:
1 (mod 11) and itself,
10 (mod 11) and itself,
2 (mod 11) and 6 (mod 11),
3 (mod 11) and 4 (mod 11),
5 (mod 11) and 9 (mod 11),
7 (mod 11) and 8 (mod 11)

As you can see for every congruence class you can find an inverse pair.
Is it true for every number?
 If so, why?

Comment: Look up Bezout's Identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,  it is not true for every number.   In fact,  it's true if and only if the modulo is of a prime number.  Anytime you have a non prime modulo, numbers that are not relatively prime to the modulo do not have an inverse, as they are zero-divisors in the ring.

For example,  in mod 6,   2 and 3 are zero divisors, and there is no inverse for either of them.